# How to give the new user to the system the User Role automatically and how to display it at the top of the website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following database design for an employee table:

- Username
- Name
- Job
- etc ..

And a role table:

- RoleID
- RoleName

Finally, a UserRole table:

- UserRoleID
- Username
- RoleID

I am developing an Intranet web-based application for my department in the company. This application should be accessible only by my department employees and it should the username of the employee with his role (access type) at the top of the website. I have four different roles; Manager, Contribute, Assisstant and User. What I want now is to do the following:

1. check the user if he is one of the department employees or not.
2. if not, he will see an error page
3. if yes, he will be able directly to access the website, and this is his first time in accessing the website, then he should get a User role and this role should be displayed at the top with the username immediately unless the Admin adds him and gives him one of the other roles.

Everything works well and fine except that the used doesn't get the User Role and the role doesn't show at the top if the user is new to the system unless the Admin determines his access in the database

So, how I can give the new user the default role and display it immediately at the top of the website besides his username?

My code-behind is as following:

```
private bool CheckUsername(string username)
    {
        if (Service.GetPerson(username).GetProperty("RES_NETID").Equals("-"))
            return false;
        else if (Security.isPMODMember(username))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

        //string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";
        //string cmdText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM employee WHERE Username = '" + username + "'";
        //using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        //{
        //    conn.Open();
        //    // Open DB connection.
        //    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
        //    {
        //        int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        //        // True (> 0) when the username exists, false (= 0) when the username does not exist.
        //        return (count > 0);
        //    }
        //}
    }


    protected void Wizard1_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string username = TextBox1.Text;
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";

        switch (Wizard1.WizardSteps[e.NextStepIndex].ID)
        {
            case "WizardStep2":

                //For checking the user        
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && CheckUsername(username))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                        conn.Open();
                        string cmdText = @"SELECT dbo.employee.Username, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.employee.JobTitle, dbo.employee.BadgeNo,
                                                ISNULL(dbo.Roles.RoleID, 3) AS RoleID, dbo.Divisions.DivisionName, dbo.Roles.RoleName
                                         FROM  dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode
                                                LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Roles RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserRole ON dbo.Roles.RoleID = dbo.UserRole.RoleID ON
                                                dbo.employee.Username = dbo.UserRole.Username
                                         WHERE     (dbo.employee.Username = @Username)";
                        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                        DataTable table = new DataTable();
                        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
                        adapter.Fill(table);

                        ObjectUser user = new ObjectUser(username, true);

                        string Name = user.Name;
                        string Username = user.ID;
                        string DivisionName = user.Org.Title;
                        string JobTitle = user.GetProperty("EMP_TITLE");
                        string BadgeNo = user.GetProperty("EMP_BADGE_NUMBER");
                        string role = "User";
                        string roleid = "3";
                        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            role = table.Rows[0]["RoleName"] as string;
                            roleid = table.Rows[0]["RoleID"].ToString();
                        }

                        lblName.Text = Name;
                        lblUsername.Text = Username;
                        lblDivision.Text = DivisionName;
                        lblJobTitle.Text = JobTitle;
                        lblBadgeNo.Text = BadgeNo;

                        lblRole.Text = role;
                        radio1.SelectedValue = roleid;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    //If the user does not exist or a blank value has been entered
                    //Cancel the nextstep redirection and display an error message in a span
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    errorSpan.InnerText = "The username specified is blank or does not belong to PMOD";
                }

                break;
            case "WizardStep3":

                break;
        }
    }




    protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        //If one of the items is selected AND a username exists in the Username session object update the user role
        string username = TextBox1.Text;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(radio1.SelectedValue) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdb;Integrated Security=True";

            //This for adding the new PMOD user to the system
            string insertUserCommand = "INSERT INTO employee (Name, Username, JobTitle, BadgeNo, EmpOrgType, DivisionCode) values (@Name, @Username, @JobTitle, @BadgeNo, @EmpOrgType, @DivisionCode)";
            string cmdText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM employee WHERE Username = '" + username + "'";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                // Open DB connection.
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                {
                    if ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 0)
                    {
                        //An object from ObjectUser class to get the user information from the Secure system and insert them to the database
                        ObjectUser user = new ObjectUser(username, true);

                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(insertUserCommand, conn);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", user.Name);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", user.GetProperty("EMP_TITLE"));
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BadgeNo", user.GetProperty("EMP_BADGE_NUMBER"));
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpOrgType", user.GetProperty("EMP_EMPTYPE"));
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DivisionCode", user.Org.Division.SapCode);
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                }
            }

            //For updating the role of the user by deleting its current role and inserting a new role
            string deleteCommand = "DELETE FROM UserRole where Username=@Username";
            string insertCommand = "INSERT INTO UserRole (RoleID,Username) values(@RoleID,@Username)";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                //using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteCommand, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //Now the insert
                    cmd.CommandText = insertCommand;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear(); //need this because still has params from del comm
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleID", radio1.SelectedValue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //infoSpan.InnerText = String.Format("The users role has been updated to - {0}", radio1.SelectedValue);
                    //cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    //infoSpan.InnerText = String.Format("The users role has been updated to - {0}", radio1.SelectedValue);
                }
            }

            Wizard1.Visible = false;
            wizard.InnerHtml = @"<p><b>The task has been done successfully.</b> <br /> <a href='UserManagement.aspx'>Edit Another User</a></p>";
        }


    }
```

I think I already did it in Wizard Step#2 as shown above, but it did now work and I don't know why. Any help please?

Comment: are you using the asp.net default membership? If so, you should use the static Role class to do this:  if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("pkellner", "admin"))
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRole("pkellner", "admin");
        }    You might also want to do a response.redirect(..) back to yourself to get it to display

Comment: Incredibly suspicious exact duplicate from another account: [How to display the default role for the user at the top of the website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293772/)